# Wordpress: How to change the clean URL of posts under a parent page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.0

I managed to create a page for all my posts and it works ok. But I want to change the clean URL of my posts. How can I change that via the wp admin area? or do I have to fiddle with the code?

For instance,

```
http://wordpress-4.com/hello-world/
```

to

```
http://wordpress-4.com/blog/hello-world/
```

I have a page called Blog and its url is,

```
http://wordpress-4.com/blog/
```

So I need to have `blog/` in front of all my posts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Permalinks in the WordPress admin.

Under custom enter into the field `blog/%postname%/`.